# How to add GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in CircleCI job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, circleci

My CircleCI job needs to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable. It keeps failing with the error: `google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File ************* was not found.`

I have encoded it by base64 before adding it to the environment variable in CircleCI. Checking upon the output, base64 decodes correctly and `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${HOME}/key.json` statement yeilds the output: `Activated service account credentials for: [test-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com]`. How can I fix this?

CircleCI config is below:

```
test-job:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.9.9
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
        name: copy to a file
        command: |
          echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS | base64 -d > ${HOME}/keys.json
          cat ${HOME}/keys.json

      - run:
        name: set to the env var
        command: |
          export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="${HOME}/keys.json" >> $BASH_ENV
          gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${HOME}/keys.json
        

      - run:
        name: install
        command: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - run:
        name: pytest
        command: |
          pytest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
https://circleci.com/docs/set-environment-variable/#set-an-environment-variable-in-a-shell-command

Try to copy
path/to/service_account.json to
/root/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json

and then try to run gcloud auth application-default